# Converting std::chrono::time_point to/from std::string

Tags: c++, strings, datetime, serialization, c++17

Consider these functions that allow to convert `std::chrono::time_point` to/from `std::string` with a **predefined** date-time format.

```
constexpr size_t log10(size_t xx) { return xx == 1 ? 0 : 1 + log10(xx/10); }

template < typename Double, size_t Precision = std::numeric_limits<Double>::digits10, typename TimePoint >
requires (TimePoint::period::den % 10 != 0) && std::is_floating_point_v<Double> && Precision <= std::numeric_limits<Double>::digits10
inline bool toString(const TimePoint& timePoint, std::string& str)
{
    Double seconds = timePoint.time_since_epoch().count();
    (seconds *= TimePoint::period::num) /= TimePoint::period::den;
    auto zeconds = std::modf(seconds,&seconds);
    time_t tt = seconds;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:")
        << std::setw(Precision+3) << std::setfill('0') << std::fixed << std::setprecision(Precision) << (tt%60)+zeconds;
    return oss && (str = oss.str(), true);
}

template < typename TimePoint > requires (TimePoint::period::den % 10 == 0)
inline bool toString(const TimePoint& timePoint, std::string& str)
{
    uint64_t feconds = timePoint.time_since_epoch().count() * TimePoint::period::num;
    time_t tt = feconds / TimePoint::period::den;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.")
        << std::setw(log10(TimePoint::period::den)) << std::setfill('0') << feconds % TimePoint::period::den;
    return oss && (str = oss.str(), true);
}

template < typename TimePoint >
bool fromString(TimePoint& timePoint, const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::tm tm{};
    if (!(iss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
        return false;
    timePoint  = {};
    timePoint += std::chrono::seconds(std::mktime(&tm));
    if (iss.eof())
        return true;
    if (iss.get() != '.')
        return false;
    std::string zz;
    if (!(iss >> zz))
        return false;
    static_assert(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num == 1 && std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den % 10 == 0);
    zz.resize(log10(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den),'0');
    size_t zeconds = 0;
    try { zeconds = std::stoul(zz); } catch (const std::exception&) { return false; }
    timePoint += std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration(zeconds);
    return true;
}
```

with usage:

```
        std::string str;
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        toString(now,str); std::cerr << "==== " << str << std::endl;
        using DD = std::chrono::duration<size_t,std::ratio<2,3>>;
        using TP = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,DD>;
        toString<double>(TP(DD(0)),str); std::cout << "==== " << str << std::endl;
        toString<double>(TP(DD(1)),str); std::cout << "==== " << str << std::endl;
        toString<double>(TP(DD(2)),str); std::cout << "==== " << str << std::endl;
        toString<double>(TP(DD(3)),str); std::cout << "==== " << str << std::endl;

        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
        str = "2017-Mar-01";                          fromString(tp,str); toString(tp,str); std::cerr << "---- " << str << std::endl;
        str = "1969-Dec-31 19:00:00.666666666666667"; fromString(tp,str); toString(tp,str); std::cerr << "---- " << str << std::endl;
```

Any suggestions to make them *faster*, *c-functions free* or *more compact*?

As the objective is to do conversions with a **predefined** date-time format the `std::locale` support of `std::ostringstream` and `std::istringstream` is useless and it is a significant slowdown. But how can I avoid this?

Comment: Not a full review - but `log10()` might not be the best choice of name, given that `std::log10()` exists.

Comment: @TobySpeight it is usually in the global names. But I believe signature accepts doubles and ints, not unsigned ones. So strong typing might save the user.

Comment: for me, it feels like the code is great candidate for a stream. The one that wraps another stream.

Comment: Is using the sequel to [std::chrono](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) considered cheating?

Answer (score 8):

## Headers and typenames

We're missing

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

And we consistently misspell the types `std::size_t`, `std::time_t`, `std::uint64_t`.

## A name collision

On systems that define a global `log10` as well as `std::log10`, there's ambiguity on the calls to our `log10`.  I suggest using a name that conveys intent, such as `digits()` (even that's a bit risky - it would be better in a private namespace).  It costs nothing to make it terminate if passed `0` as argument, too:

```
static constexpr std::size_t feconds_width(std::size_t x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 0 : 1 + feconds_width(x/10);
}
```

## Interface consistency

The two alternative forms for `toString()` need to be instantiated differently, depending on the timepoint's denominator value.  If we make `Double` default to `double`, then both can be called without explicit template arguments.

Incidentally, did you measure a performance difference between the two implementations that proved a benefit?  If so, it's worth quantifying that in a comment so that future readers understand that it's worthwhile having both versions.

## Document the assumption

This code only works when converting to or from `TimePoint` classes which have the same epoch as `std::time_t`.

## Prefer to return values over status codes

Rather than returning a status code, I'd prefer to throw an exception when conversion fails; then the return value can be used directly.  Failure in `toString()` seems especially unlikely - I think the only possible cause is running out of room in the output string and being unable to allocate more.

```
if (!oss) throw std::runtime_error("timepoint-to-string");
return oss.str();
```

If you really dislike exceptions, it's still easier on the caller to return a `std::optional` rather than return a boolean and modify a reference argument.

## Be careful with negative times

If `tt<0`, then `tt%60` can be negative.  That's not what we want.  However, since we create a `std::tm`, we can read seconds from that:

```
auto tm = std::localtime(&tt);
if (!tm) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
oss << std::put_time(tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:")
    << std::setw(Precision+3) << std::setfill('0')
    << std::fixed << std::setprecision(Precision)
    << tm->tm_sec+zeconds;
```

## Peek the '.' instead of reading it

If we leave '.' in the input stream, we can read that as part of a floating-point value:

```
double zz;
if (iss.peek() != '.' || !(iss >> zz))
    throw std::invalid_argument("decimal");
using hr_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
std::size_t zeconds = zz * hr_clock::period::den / hr_clock::period::num;
timePoint += hr_clock::duration(zeconds);
```

## Test cases seem inconsistent with the code

The test cases use month names, which require a `%b` conversion, not `%m`.
We could do with a few more test cases.

## Consider a streamable wrapper

If your main use-case is to stream dates in and out, it may be better to bypass returning a string, and instead create an object that knows how to stream directly to a `std::ostream`.  As I don't know if that's your intended use, I won't demonstrate that.

---

## Simplified code

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<typename Double = double,
         std::size_t Precision = std::numeric_limits<Double>::digits10,
         typename TimePoint>
    requires std::is_floating_point_v<Double>
          && Precision <= std::numeric_limits<Double>::digits10
inline std::string toString(const TimePoint& timePoint)
{
    auto seconds = Double(timePoint.time_since_epoch().count())
        * TimePoint::period::num / TimePoint::period::den;
    auto const zeconds = std::modf(seconds,&seconds);
    std::time_t tt(seconds);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    auto const tm = std::localtime(&tt);
    if (!tm) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
    oss << std::put_time(tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:")
        << std::setw(Precision+3) << std::setfill('0')
        << std::fixed << std::setprecision(Precision)
        << tm->tm_sec+zeconds;
    if (!oss) throw std::runtime_error("timepoint-to-string");
    return oss.str();
}

template<typename TimePoint>
TimePoint fromString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream iss{str};
    std::tm tm{};
    if (!(iss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S")))
        throw std::invalid_argument("get_time");
    TimePoint timePoint{std::chrono::seconds(std::mktime(&tm))};
    if (iss.eof())
        return timePoint;
    double zz;
    if (iss.peek() != '.' || !(iss >> zz))
        throw std::invalid_argument("decimal");
    using hr_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    std::size_t zeconds = zz * hr_clock::period::den / hr_clock::period::num;
    return timePoint += hr_clock::duration(zeconds);
}



int main()
{
    using std::chrono::system_clock;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    std::clog << "==== " << toString(now) << std::endl;
    using DD = std::chrono::duration<std::size_t,std::ratio<2,3>>;
    using TP = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,DD>;
    for (int i = 0;  i <= 3;  ++i)
        std::clog << "==== " << toString(TP(DD(i))) << std::endl;

    for (std::string s: { "2017-May-01 00:10:15", "2017-May-01 00:10:15.25",
                "2017-Mar-01", "1969-Dec-31 19:00:00.666666666666667",
                "2018", // underspecified - but succeeds as 2017-12-31
                "1752-May-5",   // out of range
                "not a date",
                })
    {
        try {
            std::clog << "---- "
                      << toString(fromString<system_clock::time_point>(s))
                      << std::endl;
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**high_resolution_clock**

Standard allows high_resolution_clock to be steady_clock or system_clock or something else. Adding high_resolution_clock to system_clock is only meaningful when high_resolution_clock is an alias of system_clock. We should just use system_clock. There is no need for high resolution as tm is only accurate to seconds.

**system_clock**

System_clock is the only clock that makes sense to be able to convert to `std::time_t` and chrono library helpfully provided `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t`.

```
auto tp_sec = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(timePoint);
auto tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t (tp_sec);
```

**duration_cast**

Instead of converting time_since_epoch().count() to seconds by hand, we can just use `auto sec_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>o(timePoint.time_since_epoch());` We can also convert to milliseconds ect. Substracting sec from ms since epoch will give us the leftover ms.

```
auto tp_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timePoint);
auto ms= (tp_ms - tp_sec).count();
```